# Would it be OK/kind to send more than one reminder emails to a recruiter in Germany?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, hiring, email-etiquette, contact

The scenario is something like this.

Sent an email, sent a reminder email after it, got reply email after reminder email, sent reply to it.

Now I am waiting for a reply again, would it be kind to send another reminder email or is it considered rude behaviour in Germany? I am wondering about your thoughts.

Assume:

*no technical difficulties. The recipient had been replying by email.

*The recruiter prefers email, as she can't be easily telephoned.

Best

Comment: At a minimum, specifying a time frame and a general summary of what you are waiting on will be helpful.  Sending a reminder email if you've been waiting on information for an hour would be rude.  Sending a reminder email if you've been waiting for weeks would not be.  If you are waiting on time-sensitive information (i.e. you've got an interview scheduled tomorrow and you're trying to confirm location), that is different than if you are waiting on something less time-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you for reply @JustinCave. There is 3 days between my first email and reminder email. It has passed 4 days without getting any reply. Its a little bit time sensitive , because I need to apply to visa for the travel Germany.

Comment: the simple answer is, yes, it's fine - go for it

Answer (score 1):

"There is 3 days between my first email and reminder email. It has passed 4 days without getting any reply". Yes send the reminder email and emphasize that it's a time sensitive matter.